# Div on mouse over shows different pictures

Tags: jquery

How to achieve with JQuery that when I move mouse over some div, it shows different pictures(backgrounds ). For example, my div id="slide" have width="100px, so when mouse in width position  0

Like on http://qgallery.quadrifolia.de/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look into `.hover()` or the [jQuery Cycle plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/) if you have multiple background images.